# Existe a possibilidade de receber um objeto nulo proveniente de outro fragmento em Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment

O problema é o seguinte: Tenho dois fragmentos, o primeiro possui uma lista, que se clicada, envia um objeto para ser editado no fragmento B. No fragmento A também existe um botão de inclusão que ao ser clicado abre o fragmento B para cadastrar determinadas informações. O código do fragmento A é este:

```
public class AlarmFragment extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private ListView lista;
FloatingActionButton btnAddAlarme;

public AlarmFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);



    TimerDAO dao = new TimerDAO(getActivity());

    List<Timer> timers = dao.getListaAgendamentos();
    dao.close();

    int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    ListaAgendamentosCadastradosAdapter adapter = new ListaAgendamentosCadastradosAdapter(timers, layout, getActivity());
    //ArrayAdapter<Timer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Timer>(getActivity(), layout, timers);

    lista = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listaAgendamentosCadastrados);

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Timer agendamentoClicado = (Timer)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            CadastroAlarmFragment cadastroAlarmFragment = new CadastroAlarmFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("agendamentoSelecionado", agendamentoClicado);
            cadastroAlarmFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, cadastroAlarmFragment, cadastroAlarmFragment.getTag()).commit();
        }
    });

    btnAddAlarme = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddAlarme);

    btnAddAlarme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CadastroAlarmFragment cadastroAlarmFragment = new CadastroAlarmFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.content_main,
                    cadastroAlarmFragment,
                    cadastroAlarmFragment.getTag()
            ).commit();

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Seguindo as buscas na Internet, realizo o envio do objeto já existente do fragmento A para o fragmento B através de um Serializable. Quando o segundo fragmento é aberto, eu realizo uma verificação para saber se o que veio através do serializable é um objeto para ser editado ou se preciso cadastrar um novo. O código do fragmento B é o seguinte:

```
    public class CadastroAlarmFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView txt_idAgendamento;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    TextClock tcHoraAtual;
    Spinner cbSelecaoValvulaCadastroAgendamento;
    EditText etTempoDeFuncionamentoCadastroAgendamento;
    Button btnSalvaAgendamento;
    ToggleButton btnAtivaAgendamento;
    Long milli;
    String actualTime;
    Boolean clickTime = false;
    Context context;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    int hour, minute;
    String horaMinuto;
    public CadastroAlarmHelper helper;


    public CadastroAlarmFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro_alarm2, container, false);

        helper = new CadastroAlarmHelper(view);

        tcHoraAtual = (TextClock)view.findViewById(R.id.tcHoraAtual);
        cbSelecaoValvulaCadastroAgendamento = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.cbSelecaoValvulaCadastroAgendamento);
        etTempoDeFuncionamentoCadastroAgendamento = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etTempoDeFuncionamentoCadastroAgendamento);
        btnSalvaAgendamento = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSalvaAgendamento);
        btnAtivaAgendamento = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAtivaAgendamento);
        txt_idAgendamento = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_idAgendamento);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        final Timer agendamentoParaSerAlterado = (Timer)bundle.getSerializable("agendamentoSelecionado");
        if(agendamentoParaSerAlterado!= null)
        {
           btnSalvaAgendamento.setText("Salvar Alterações");
           helper.colocaAgendamentoNaTela(agendamentoParaSerAlterado);
           tcHoraAtual.setText(agendamentoParaSerAlterado.getDataHoraInicio());
        }
        else if(agendamentoParaSerAlterado == null){
            tcHoraAtual.setFormat24Hour(getTime());
        }

        this.context = getActivity();
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        //Cria a instancia do calendario
        final java.util.Calendar calendar =  timePickerFragment.calendar;

        //Criando Intent pra classe AlarmReceiver
        final Intent intent =  new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);


        loadSpinnerData();

        tcHoraAtual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickTime = true;
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "TIMEPICKER");
            }
        });


        btnSalvaAgendamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String tempo = etTempoDeFuncionamentoCadastroAgendamento.getText().toString();
                if(tempo.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Digite o tempo de funcionamento!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{

                    Timer timer = helper.pegaInfoIrrigacaoCadastro();
                    TimerDAO dao = new TimerDAO(getActivity());

                    if(horaMinuto!=null) {
                        horaMinuto = tcHoraAtual.getText().toString();
                        hour = Integer.parseInt(horaMinuto.substring(0, 2));
                        minute = Integer.parseInt(horaMinuto.substring(3, 5));
                    }

                    else if(agendamentoParaSerAlterado == null)
                    {
                        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                        final int _id = ((int)System.currentTimeMillis())*-1;
                        txt_idAgendamento.setText(String.valueOf(_id));

                        intent.putExtra("extra", "on"+tempo);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), _id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        //Definir o AlarmManager
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                        dao.salvaTimer(timer);
                    }
                    else{

                        agendamentoParaSerAlterado.setId(agendamentoParaSerAlterado.getId());
                        dao.alteraTimer(timer);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Alterações Salvas!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    }
                    dao.close();

                    AlarmFragment alarmFragment = new AlarmFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.content_main,
                            alarmFragment,
                            alarmFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
                }
            }
        });

        btnAtivaAgendamento.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){

                }
                else {
                    String idAgendamento = (String) txt_idAgendamento.getText();
                    int _idAgendamento = Integer.valueOf(idAgendamento);
                    alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), _idAgendamento, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
                    //put extra string into intent
                    //Tells the clock that youpressed "cancelar alarme"
                    intent.putExtra("extra","off");
                    //Para a musica
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public String getTime()
    {
        milli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date result = new Date(milli);
        actualTime = sdf.format(result);
        return actualTime;
    }

    private void loadSpinnerData()
    {
        TimerDAO dao = new TimerDAO(getActivity());
        Cursor servicesCursor = dao.getServicesCursor();

        String[]from = {"nomeValvula"};
        int[] to ={android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, servicesCursor, from, to, 0);

        cbSelecaoValvulaCadastroAgendamento.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }


}
```

Porém, sempre que clico no botão "novo" no Fragmento A, o Serializable não é enviado, e quando o fragmento B começa, é verificado se é um objeto para ser editado ou se é um novo. Quando isso acontece o sistema me dá o seguinte erro:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.cabral.irriga, PID: 24858
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
 at com.example.cabral.irriga.CadastroAlarmFragment.onCreateView(CadastroAlarmFragment.java:90)
```

Que é exatamente na verificação onde preciso saber se é um novo, ou se é para ser editado, já que o Serializable está vazio o erro acontece.
Então, existe alguma outra maneira para eu realizar esta tarefa?
Visto que em Activities posso enviar uma intent vazia e fazer o mesmo trabalho tentado acima?
Alguma outra sugestão para solucionar o caso?

Comment: Tenta receber seu argumento assim: `final Timer agendamentoParaSerAlterado = (Timer)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("agendamentoSelecionado");`

Comment: Funcionou Cara! Muito Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta Rodrigo. Abraços. Boa sorte!

Comment: Para efeitos de compilação funcionou, mas na prática não. O null pointer não acontece mais, porém eu não estou a receber nenhuma Intent no fragmento B. Como envio esta intent para o fragmento?

Comment: Você está debugando? está acontecendo qual erro agora?

Comment: Estou debugando sim. O que acontece agora é que o objeto não está sendo passado do Fragmento A para o Fragmento B. O trecho: 

    Timer agendamentoParaSerAlterado = Timer)getActivity().getIntent().
    getSerializableExtra("agend‌​amentoSelecionado");

Sempre está recebendo Null.

Comment: Tenta passar assim:  `context.getIntent().putExtra("agendamentoSelecionado", agendamentoClicado)` no Fragmento A

Comment: Mesmo criando um context e fazendo ele receber this.context dentro do construtor do fragmento A. O compilador apresenta: Cannot resolve method 'getIntent();'

Comment: Cara, fui olhar direito aqui e percebi que não há problema nenhum com seu `serializable`. Do jeito que estava, funciona corretamente. Tente observar se ao clicar no botão, se você realmente está enviado um `Timer`. Verifique se está conseguindo pegar o item corretamente atraves do `getItemAtPosition` . Estou desconfiando que realmente não está passando nada. Aconselho no seu fragmento B você colocar uma verificação, por exemplo `if (bundle != null)`

Comment: Voltei para a forma inicial, e para o problema inicial também. Quando é um item já existente o `getItemAtPosition` funciona perfeitamente e a linha: `final Timer agendamentoParaSerAlterado = (Timer)args.getSerializable("agendamentoSelecionado");` também. O problema, é que se eu fizer uma verificação como `if(bundle != null)` e declarar a linha acima dentro deste `if` o código para de funcionar porque existem métodos mais abaixo que utilizam a variável `agendamentoParaSerAlterado`. E se eu a declarar global, ela precisa ser final, e sendo `final`eu não consigo atribuir valor a ela dentro do if.

Comment: Bom, eu peguei exatamente a parte que você envia e a parte que você recebe os dados através do `serializable` e funcionou perfeitamente passando um outro objeto qualquer. Acho que o problema seu aqui é outra coisa que nada tem a ver com o `serializable`. Particularmente não vejo nenhum problema você criar uma variável global e a verificação do `bundle` é somente saber se o problema é no `serializable` ou problema no objeto que está a enviar. Acho que não consigo ajudar muito porque não tem como reproduzir todo código aqui.

Comment: Obrigado pela força, mas solucionei da seguinte forma: No botão de inclusão do Fragmento A enviei uma String no `bundle` para garantir que ele não fosse nulo, e no Fragmento B mantive meu código, somente verificando se o objeto era nulo. Se for, então, cadastre um novo, se o objeto estiver preenchido então, edite o objeto. De toda forma, muito obrigado pelo esforço e pela ajuda!